# Integrate html site into Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, integration

I made a masonry gallery using html, css and javascript.
Now I would like to integrate [this site (dangra.uber.space)](https://dangra.uber.space) into [my current wordpress (grafschafftdesign.de)](https://www.grafschafftdesign.de) installation.

I found [this guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website) about the topic. It says:

> In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.
>
> ```
> <?php 
> Short and sweet */
> define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
> require('./wp-blog-header.php');
> ?>
>
> <?php
> require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
> get_header(); 
> ?>
> ```

I have no clue about php yet. I tried to rename my index.html into index.php but instead of running the site the browser would attempt to download it. After some research I found out it had to do with php handlers in the .htaccess file, but honestly, I have no clue and am completly lost.

**Question**
How do I integrate my custom html page into my wordpress website?